# Set URL to load iframe in a Django template

Tags: javascript, html, django, iframe

I want to load an `iframe` into a Django template. The template is getting loaded correctly, but in place of the `iframe`, the template itself is getting embedded inside the parent template. The code relevant is given below:

```
<body>
    <p>
        <strong>Player: {{player.username}}</strong>&nbsp;
        <div id="playerid">{{player.id}}</div><br>
        <iframe id="encoder_iframe" height=75% width="50%" src="testgame.html"></iframe>
        <br>
        <strong>Last score:</strong>&nbsp;
        <span id="scores"></span><br><br>
        <strong>Game state:</strong>
        <div id="gamestate"></span>
    </p>
    <br>
</body>
```

*testgame.html* is a file located in the same directory as this HTML template, but it doesn't load. In its place, the parent template itself appears. I looked around Stack Overflow, and from some of the posts I gather that I need to set the `src` attribute of the `iframe` to a Django view, which will load the `iframe` separately. Is this correct? If so, how do I configure the URL (i.e. set the path to the view)?

Comment: The src of an iframe is exactly the same as any other URL. If you're expecting Django to serve it, you need to do exactly the same as you would with any other Django page.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, you have to create the view to load the template.  The simplest way to do this is to use generic [TemplateView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateView).  Add this url to `urlpatterns` in your `urls.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

url(r'^testgame/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="testgame.html"),
                   name='testgame'),
```

And `<iframe>` tag will look like:

```
<iframe id="encoder_iframe" height=75% width="50%" src="{% url 'testgame' %}">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved my problem. I had one other doubt - in this case, my HTML file is locally present, so it works. But if my HTML is hosted as a URL and not as a local file anywhere , e.g. http://www.example.com/testgame.html, then how should I set the "src" attribute?

Comment: `src` attribute should point to url where this html is served. If you serve it from your app then my answer shows how to do it.  If this html is served from external (not yours) site then set `src` to `example.com/testgame.html`.

Comment: OK. In that case, there should be a view to actually load that HTML, right? I wanted to know how I can call that view from the parent template, or the urls.py file.

Comment: No. The view and corresponding `url()` is needed only to serve this html template from your site. If the source of html is some other site then you just point to that site in the `src` tag.  If fact `<iframe<` tag makes no difference between your and external site. It just loads html from specified url.

Comment: I have tried the above steps. I get error "localhost refused to connect". I have also added 'locahost' to ALLOWED_HOSTS attribute in settings.py file. Any suggestions for fixing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use outside url, you can do like below:

```
<iframe id="encoder_iframe" height=75% width="50%" src="http://www.example.com/testgame.html"></iframe>
```

add src with `http://` or `https://`, otherwise for example it will turn to something like `http://127.0.0.1:8000/www.example.com/testgame.html`

Comment: Your approach worked for me, though it wasn't clear wny at first, apparently, by prefixing the URL with "https://" or "http://", you are telling Django that this is a valid URL and should not be treated as a local resource. Literary had to the following for it to work:

`
 const str = docItem.getAttribute( 'data')

    const url =str.replace("'https://",'')

    document.querySelector('.responsive-iframe').src = 'https://'+url
`