# How to put template into iframe?

Tags: python, django, iframe, path

The very similiar problem as mine I found here: [Set URL to load iframe in a Django template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28268574/set-url-to-load-iframe-in-a-django-template) but it doesn't help.

Having a route in my urls.py written as (...) `path('rejestracja/', views.rejestracja, name = 'rejestracja'),`(...) where the view is to render page named rejestracja.html,
I have to put the content of it into iframe. And I do it assigning `src = "{% url 'rejestracja' %}"`.
Unfortunatelly the iframe is showing me an error: "Page localhost is blocked"
"Server localhost denied connection."
ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE
The strange thing is, source of iframe shows me content of rejestracja.html.
It means, I think, my code is ok, but somewhere I have any restrictions. But I have no idea which, how and where... 
Could someone tell me what is wrong, or at least, where to look for solution?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/clickjacking

Set `X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'`

Comment: Yes, this is the right solution. The other way is to install "Ignore X-Frame headers" add-on to Opera browser (only development stage) ;)
I have found what is going about, reading console output in Opera's DevTools. I have to read more about security risks. Or perhaps it is a good time to talk about it here...